# PHP repeating piece of code wtih access to variables

Tags: php

How to repeat the same PHP snippet in different PHP files?
For example I define the variable `$user`, then I insert PHP code, which have an access to this variable. 
**Update:**
I'm going to use this with if statement

> Example(without if statement):

```
    function sanitizeString($var)
    {
    $var = htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    return mysql_real_escape_string($var);
    }
    $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
    $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);
    //code i want to repeat in different files
    $user=$user;
    $pass=$pass;
    #salt generation
    $salt=uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
    #Add data to tables
    queryMysql("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES('$user', '".hash('sha512',$pass+$salt)."', '$salt', '$cookie_value')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO passwordreset VALUES('$user', NULL, NULL)");
    //end of code to repeat
```

Comment: `$user=$user` What is that for? I'm still not sure what you are trying to do. You are storing this data in a database, are you trying to *retrieve the data* from the database in another script? You are on the right path if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [*functions*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) with [*parameters*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php), that's what they're for. Snippets of code that can be reused in a different context with different variables.

Comment: If I use `function()` that use `$user` inside, but `$user` was defined outside this function, will it work?

Comment: inside parameters wont effect others

Comment: @warlord That's what you use *parameters* for that you *pass into* the function. Please see the linked manual again.

Comment: @war Looking at it I'm still not sure what you're trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: @deceze There is a piece of code I want to repeat and there are variables defined outside this piece of code. How to repeat this code and allow him to access defined variables?

Comment: @war Why not use functions again? You could use *anonymous functions/closures* which close up the `$user` variable, but that seems like a very weird use case. How to best structure your code is hard to tell without more information.

Answer (score 1):

Make classes and methods

```
class User
{
   public $user;
   public function User($name)
   {
      $user = $name;
   }
}

$User = new User('name1');
echo $User->user;
$User = new User('name2');
echo $User->user;
$User = new User('name3');
echo $User->user;
$User = new User('name4');
echo $User->user;
```

Output: name1name2name3name4

Comment: A bit overkill, no? Apparently the OP needs to understand *functions* first.

Comment: @deceze I understand functions

Comment: @war I see, didn't sound like it from your question. Then I'm not sure what the question is about, really. Can you update it with a code example of what you're trying to do and what problem you have doing it using functions?

Answer (score 0):

U Can add the code or variable in one php file and then include that file where ever u want 
U can see the example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score -1):

*(Removed [global keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) as it is not necessary in this case)*

One method is to use the $GLOBALS variable, which is accessible anywhere much like $_SERVER, $_POST etc. See [Superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). As Deceze mentioned, **global variables are typically not the best solution**, as they are prone to causing accidental errors. For more information about this, [give this a read](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

```
$GLOBALS['user'] = "RadGH";
include "my_file.php";
```

my_file.php:

```
echo $GLOBALS['user'];
```

---

From Bondeye in a comment, using a **constant** is preferred when dealing with data that does not need to be changed. One of the problems with globals is that somewhere down the line data may be changed or referenced accidentally. Since constants cannot be changed, that is not the case.

```
define('USER', 'RadGH');
include "my_file.php";
```

my_file.php:

```
echo USER;
```

Comment: If you want to use globals, use them right! For this consider constants before globals http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: We must use PHP global variables carefully, only if there is no other ways

Comment: If you're just `including` files, all the code is in the same scope anyway. No need for `global` shenanigans whatsoever.

Comment: Updated to reflect these comments. I agree that global variables should be avoided for "best practice", especially in cases where a constant would be appropriate (data will never change). However, there are always exceptions or scenarios in which these methods are acceptable - not always as the "better solution", but often as the "cheaper" or "faster" solution, especially if using another method requires some rewriting of existing code.

Comment: Since there are no such constraints to the question, I'd assume there is no legacy baggage which needs to be taken care of, so I'd rather prefer you talk about the *better* solution first than sending the OP down a path of misery with an unnecessarily cheap solution. Both `$_GLOBALS` and constants are inappropriate where a function parameter will do.

Comment: Functions pass data into a variable, that would be my first suggestion - but you had already covered that. OOP as Bondye described is an alternative, although perhaps overkill. If neither of those solutions works for him (for whatever reason, I'm sure they would), these are an alternative. There are still situations in which the global keyword is acceptable, eg. writing a script *dedicated* to editing contents of a file. Make the file handle be a global and access it within all of your files, instead of duplicating the $fh parameter on every single function. Why would this be a bad thing?